# fetching columns from assetLibrary

Tags: sharepoint-online, ajax

I have a assetLibrary , which consist of videos. I have a custom field called Description.

```
`${rootUrl}('Vidz')/items?$select=Description&$top=2`
```

this is the url i am passing via ajax call ,but i am getting null for description, also for getting thumbnail and name of file what should i give in  select

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can fire the query without `$select` statement i.e. `${rootUrl}('Vidz')/items?$top=2`. This will give you all fields and then you can check which you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the name of the column that is returned. I created an OOB library and added a new column 'Description' and the value returned for that column is actually 'Description0'. You can use the browser's developer tools to check or place this somewhere in the success portion of the ajax request to see the results in the console.

```
// display all column results in console
var items = data.d.results;
for(var i=0; i< items.length; i++)  {
    console.log(items[i]);
}
```